# API Graph Facebook - Creation page User TEST

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to use the Graph api to create pages. So I have an application type Entreprise, and a Test User. I tried this:

```
Post request to [userTest_id]/accounts/
Params:
{
  "name": "Test Page One",
  "about": "This is the first page created to check the api",
  "cover_photo": {
    "url": "https://i.etsystatic.com/6293506/r/il/ea9cf8/1809124703/il_fullxfull.1809124703_swn3.jpg"
  },
  "picture": "https://i.etsystatic.com/6293506/r/il/ea9cf8/1809124703/il_fullxfull.1809124703_swn3.jpg",
  "category_list": "[\"174177802634376\"]"
}
```

I use user token
I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '[userTest_id]' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "ATSiLLBx2O1yOuPRFxq4r4V"
  }
}
```

I've followed this doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating

What I'm missing plz ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear - you mean an actual Test User, and not just an account that was added to the app in the "Tester" role, yes?

Comment: @CBroe Yes it's an actual Test User (in the menu Test User and not in the Roles menu).

Comment: And it is just the numeric user ID in your request URL, without the square brackets around it?

Comment: @CBroe, yes just the id.

Comment: @CBroe, If the end point and the params are corrects ... I'm afraid that I'm not correctly having the permissions...and I'm not sure if I should have apply for them even If it's a userTest ?

Comment: Of course your access token needs to include the permissions the documentation says are necessary, as granted. But the point of using test users (or testers, for that matter), is that you can ask those for any permissions, _before_ you submit your app for review.

Comment: @CBroe yes, I have those permissions for the test user but not for the application... can this be the problem ? plz

Comment: You can not have permissions "for" an application. Your application can have the permissions _approved_ in review - so that you will be able to ask _all_ users for them, not just those with a role in your app. // Do the permissions really show as granted, when you debug the token using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ ?

Comment: @CBroe yes they are.

Comment: Hm, could be that it is the wrong app type perhaps? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types

Comment: @CBroe, I've found the probleme... I was not using the right token ... now It shows me error in param (invalid category param) ... Thanks a lot. I work on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API doesn't allow creating Pages in the "real world" scope. You may do it for test users (created on the Role tab) or, in production, you have to get special approval from Facebook (not just permission).